# Django-haystack and django-pagination not working together?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-haystack, django-pagination

I use haystack with whoosh, and django 1.3. In my url I have:

```
url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
```

I created custom template in app: search/seach.html:

```
{% if page.object_list %}                                                        

{% autopaginate page.object_list 3 %}
{% for arg in page.object_list %}
...
{% endfor%}
{% paginate %}
```

My search works fine! Also rendered pagination (with paginate templatetag) is correct. But when I try to go to next page, I get this error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?page=2&q=Aktualno%C5%9B%C4%87
```

Can You help me? Whats wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I made django-haystack and django-pagination work by using a custom SearchView that extends the SearchView of django-haystack. Just comment out or remove the `(paginator, page) = self.build_page()` and the page and paginator context variable.

Below is my custom SearchView.

```
class SearchView(SearchView):

def create_response(self):
    """
    Generates the actual HttpResponse to send back to the user.
    """
    # (paginator, page) = self.build_page()

    context = {
        'query': self.query,
        'form': self.form,
        # 'page': page,
        # 'paginator': paginator,
        'suggestion': None,
        'results': self.results
    }

    if self.results and hasattr(self.results, 'query') and self.results.query.backend.include_spelling:
        context['suggestion'] = self.form.get_suggestion()

    context.update(self.extra_context())
    return render_to_response(self.template, context, context_instance=self.context_class(self.request))
```

and in the template paginate using the results context variable:

```
  {% autopaginate results 2 %}
  {% for result in results %}
      {{ result.attribute }}
  {% endfor %}
  {% paginate %}
```

Thats it :)

Answer (score 2):

In Django 1.8.4 you just have to replace page for page_obj in your template.

Example:

```
{% for arg in page_obj.object_list %}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `haystack` default SearchView's `page` doesn't support `django-pagination`.
If you want to use `django-pagination`, you can Inherit the SearchView and ad a new context variable to store the search result. And then you can use this context variable to pagination.

```
def create_response(self):
    (paginator, page) = self.build_page()        
    context = {
        'query': self.query,
        'form': self.form,
        'page': page,
        'results': self.results,
        'paginator': paginator,
        'suggestion': None,
        }
```